# C# Property and PropertyChanged Threading Fail

Tags: c#, multithreading, properties, locking, polymorphism

In the end, I am receiving the thread cannot access because it is owned by another thread. However, this is not releated to UI (directly). The exception is only thrown when I try to set the property of an object, not the member itself. It works fine if I set the member directly, but I lose my PropertyChanged event. *Please, if I am over complicating this let me know! I could not think of other way to return a property to MainWindow.*

You can fast forward to Class #3 below for results. At the highest level I have three classes involved: MainWindow, OCXComms, and ZServer. When the listen button is pressed it calls on a startup method in OCXComms and is responsible for the creation of the ZServer instance as shown:

**CLASS #1**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private OCUComms comms;

        ......

    private void roxListenBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Debugger Shows Main Thread
        comms.StartOutput();
    }

   void comms_IsClientConnectedChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        connectionStatusLbl.Content = "Connected - No Control";
        connectionStatusLbl.Foreground = myWarningBrush;

        roverControlBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        manualControlRB.IsEnabled = true;
    }

        ......
}
```

Next, the ZServer object is constructed on the "MainThread" via StartOutput. This works fine.

**CLASS #2**

```
public sealed class OCXComms : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        private static OCXComms instance;
        private static readonly object instanceSync = new object();

        private Boolean _isClientConnected = false;
        private bool isEnabled;

          .....

     public static OCXComms Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (instanceSync)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new OCXComms();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private OCXComms()
    {
        isEnabled = false;
        _isControllerEnabled = false;
        _isKeyboardEnabled = false;

        worker = new System.Timers.Timer();

        worker.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(worker_Elapsed);

        Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(Default_PropertyChanged);
    }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private void OnClientConnectedChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsClientConnected"));
    }

    void server_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsClientConnected = server.getIsClientConnected();
    } 

        public void StartOutput()
    {
            if (isEnabled)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine("ZServer started on: " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

            //Debugger Shows Main Thread
            this.server = new ZServer(Properties.Settings.Default.ListeningPort);
            this.server.PropertyChanged += server_PropertyChanged;
            this.server.Start();

            IsEnabled = true;

    }
}
```

**This is where the problem happens. Note the two different attempts** (only shown here, not actually in syntax). Without breakpoints the client and server just hang, if a breakpoint is set a first change exception informs me that a thread is trying to access information owned by another thread. It is somewhat clear to me that the ZServer was created on the "MainThread" and at this point I am on the the listener thread. I have no doubt this is the problem. However, I am unsure how to proceed. Most of my research leads to Dispatcher, but I am not in it the main window.... "I am three classes deep ;)" I have tried locking, monitoring, new threads, all without success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**CLASS #3**

```
public class ZServer
{
    private Thread listenThread;
    private Boolean _isClientConnected = false;

    public ZServer(String sIP, int iPort)
    {
        InitializeServer(sIP, iPort);
    }

       private void InitializeServer(String sIP, int iPort)
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(sIP), iPort);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients_DoWork));
        this.listenThread.Name = "Listen Thread";

    }

            public Boolean IsClientConnected
    {
        get 
        {
        return _isClientConnected;
        }

        private set 
        {
            _isClientConnected = value;
            OnClientConnectedChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnClientConnectedChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsClientConnected"));
    }


     private void ListenForClients_DoWork()
    {
        // Start the Server Listening for Clients to connect while blocking.
        this.tcpListener.Start();

        while (!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {

                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                this._isClientConnected = true;  //<== This Works
                this.IsClientConnected = true; //This causes client and server to hang. Possible deadlock?
                ........
            }
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Closed from Another Thread: " + socketEx.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ZServer: unhandled exception in ListenForClients: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ListenForClients exiting...");
    }

    public Boolean getIsClientConnected()
    {
        lock (_clientConnectedLock)
        {
            return _isClientConnected;
        }
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is simple, you create a form on one thread, making that thread the UI thread for that form.  However, in server you launch a new thread (which doesn't own that form) which when client is connected raises an event, and through handlers that event gets propagated to `comms_IsClientConnectedChanged`.  However, that propagation is still on that worker thread, and not UI thread.

Thus when that handler code calls `connectionStatusLbl.Content`, it calls into a UI control by a non-UI-owning thread.  And that's a no-no.

Use `.InvokeRequired` and `.Invoke()` inside `comms_IsClientConnectedChanged` when accessing form or any of its descendant controls.  This will solve your issue.

Comment: I would have never looked there. Thank you for your help! I was going cross-eyed.